# Hamcrest: test list contains an item that has a private field with a certain value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I have this class:

```
public class A {
    private int x;

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And a method in a different class I want to test:

```
public class B {
    public List underTest() {
        int x = doStuff();
        return Collections.singletonList(new A(x));
    }

    private int doStuff() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I want to test that, at the end of `underTest()`, the item in the returned list contains an `x` field equal to a certain value.  I've written this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@Test
public void Test1() {
    List result = bInstance.underTest();
    assertThat(result, contains(hasProperty("x", is(1))));
}
```

But junit complains that `item 0: No Property "x"` for my test case.

How can I test this? The only thing I can think of is to add a public getter for `getX()`, then iterate through the returned `List` and check every element. Remember that, while the method returns a `singletonList`, the return type is just `List`, so it *could* be changed in the future to have multiple values in it.

Comment: @Michael added imports

Comment: Hamcrest in their javadoc says that the property should be a JavaBean property which means it probably requires having a public getter for the field `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's first worth saying that testing class internals like this is not a good idea, except maybe in very special cases. Your tests will be brittle and changes that would normally be totally safe - i.e. renaming a field - may now cause your automated build to fail. You should test *external behaviour*, not implementation details.

It seems like you'd be better off implementing `equals` and `hashCode` in your class `A`, so then you can simply do:

```
contains(new A(1))
```

With that said, if you do have a genuinely good reason to do this (and such cases will be rare) then you cannot use `hasProperty` for this.

From [the JavaDoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

> Creates a matcher that matches when the examined object has a JavaBean
>   property with the specified name whose value satisfies the specified
>   matcher.

I believe this implies that you would need a method named `getX`.

You shouldn't add such a method just for the purpose of a test, but you can write your own general-purpose [`Matcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) implementation that will use reflection to examine the fields of the class.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
class ReflectiveFieldMatcher<T> extends BaseMatcher<Object>
{
    private final String fieldName;
    private final T expectedValue;

    ReflectiveFieldMatcher(final String fieldName, final T expectedValue)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(final Object obj)
    {
        for (final Field field : obj.getClass().getFields())
        {
            if (field.getName().equals(fieldName))
            {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try
                {
                    Object value = field.get(obj);
                    return expectedValue.equals(value);
                }
                catch (final IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description)
    {
        description.appendText("Object with field '" + fieldName + "' with value: " + expectedValue);
    }
}
```

Your example would now look like this:

```
assertThat(result, contains(new ReflectiveFieldMatcher<>("x", 1)));
```

Comment: That's absolutely a good point. I actually don't like this mechanism of testing (using a private field), but I can't think of another way to do it. My class is essentially an HTML generator, and I don't want to compare a massive block of HTML, in which only the `x` attribute would change, and I also don't want to deal with DOM parsing. The issue is the returning of a list, in which only a single element needs to contain the value in question.

Comment: @ewok I've done a similar thing for XML before. For those tests, I used [XMLUnit](https://www.xmlunit.org/) to compare the actual output with an `expected_output.xml` in my test resources folder. It sounds like you'd be better off doing something like that. I think XMLUnit should work to compare HTML (well, [it says it can](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/index.html))